# Angular RouterModule - url navigation always "404 Not Found" after production build

Tags: angular, typescript

## Background

I've recently built my first Angular 4 app, and used angular-cli to generate a production build for an Apache server, using the following command on an Ubuntu terminal:

**ng build --base-href /my-new-app/ -prod**

The reason it's like this is because my server contain other apps hosted by apache that are on addresses like this:

**http://my-server.com/my-other-app**

## The Problem

My app-routing-module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MyComponent } from './my-comp/my-component.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/my-comp', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'my-comp',  component: MyComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/my-comp', pathMatch: 'full'}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

If I acess the app via **http://my-server.com/my-new-app** it redirects properly to **http://my-server.com/my-new-app/my-comp**, and if I navigate using the app it goes fine, but a F5 to refresh or pressing enter on the search bar with **http://my-server.com/my-new-app/my-comp** send me to a "404 not found".

On development it works fine, using **ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --open**, however it opens on **localhost:4200/my-comp** so I'm guessing it's not really the same.

What am I doing wrong on the production build that every route except the first one end on a 404 error?

Comment: Do you have `<base href="/">` on your index.html? If so, what is href in your production build?

Comment: Yes I do @Gosha_Fighten, it's <base href="/"> in development and <base href="/my-new-app/"> on the develpment build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `.htaccess` file on root and paste this inside

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution will also work for IIS, although for IIS, it will require to import this .htaccess file within the URL Rewrite module.